# ASP.NET session isn't saving List data between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to store some custom objects into a List, storing it between postbacks via a Session. But for some reason the List isn't updating to show on Debug, or the GridView.

```
List<Book> booklist;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["InitialBooklist"] == null) {
        booklist = new List<Book>();
        Session.Add("InitialBooklist", booklist);
    } else {
        booklist = Session["InitialBooklist"] as List<Book>;
        GridView1.DataSource = booklist;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        foreach (Book book in booklist) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(book.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the appropriate piece of the method that adds the button to a row in a table (a different thing from the GridView), and gives it an click handler...

```
    TableCell addButtonCell = new TableCell();
    Button addButton = new Button();
    addButton.Text = "Add";
    addButton.Click += delegate(object sender1, EventArgs e1) {
        addButton_Click(sender1, e1, title, author, price, coverURL, ISBN, numPages, amazonURL);
    };
    addButtonCell.Controls.Add(addButton);
    row.Cells.Add(addButtonCell);
```

Finally, here's the click handler...

```
public void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, String title, String author, String price, String coverURL, String ISBN, String numPages, String amazonURL) {
    booklist.Add(new Book(title, author, price, coverURL, ISBN, numPages, amazonURL));
}
```

Comment: look like your coding wrong. Why you do not check isPostBack Page_Load event?. If you do not check isPostBack, your booklist is always will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Please add and checkpage isPostBack in Page_Load. Please try like that way but i have not teseted yet.

```html
List<Book> booklist;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 if(!isPostBack){
  if (Session["InitialBooklist"] == null) {
   booklist = new List<Book>();
   Session.Add("InitialBooklist", booklist);
  } else {
   booklist = Session["InitialBooklist"] as List<Book>;
   GridView1.DataSource = booklist;
   GridView1.DataBind();

   foreach (Book book in booklist) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(book.ToString());
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Added it, didn't do anything unfortunately. List is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Is your page session "readonly"?
Do check your page attributes.

I also made a slight modification below:

```
List<Book> booklist;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["InitialBooklist"] == null) {
        booklist = new List<Book>();
        Session.Add("InitialBooklist", booklist);
    }

if(!isPostBack){
        booklist = Session["InitialBooklist"] as List<Book>;
        GridView1.DataSource = booklist;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        foreach (Book book in booklist) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(book.ToString());
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. The list is still showing as null.